# Cypress doesn't redirect to logged in page after external auth redirect

Tags: authentication, oauth, automated-tests, cypress

After submitting login details, user is redirected to an external authentication service and then should redirect to login page. Cypress test redirects to auth service corrently, but then redirects back to the authentication service

This is what I have so far

```
  it('logs in', () => {
cy.visit(Cypress.env('appUrl'));
cy.get(locators.Button).click();
cy.origin('https://auth-service.ee', () => {
cy.get('[data-tab="mobile-id"]').eq(1).click();
cy.get("#mid-personal-code").clear().type("60001017771");
cy.get("#mid-phone-number").clear().type("59700366{enter}");
})

cy.visit("https://loggedinpage.com/organizations/2/details",  {timeout: 5000});
cy.location('pathname').should('eq', 'details');
cy.contains('Hello, World!');
cy.pause()


});
```

And this is where it redirects back to auth.

[image: And this is where it redirects back to auth]

It does use an oauth2 auth cookie, is that what's missing in my test?
Any help appreciated

Comment: I would note that `cy.location('pathname')` is everything after the origin, so `.should('eq', '/organizations/2/details')` - but I don't see that before the pause is logged, so guess it's not actually in the test.

Comment: That aside, normally there's a submit that triggers return to prior page. If no submit button, what triggers the return?

Comment: @user16695029 pushing the enter button triggers the return  cy.get("#mid-phone-number").clear().type("59700366{enter}");

Comment: Ok, I see it now. What is the location after `(page load)`?

Comment: It's the /organizations/2/details page and as you can see from the image, it redirects back to /auth/mid/init

Comment: Ok, so the auth redirects back to `appUrl` and you then try to visit the details page within the app domain. What happens if before visiting details you try to assert `cy.location('origin').should('eq', Cypress.env('appUrl'))`

Answer (score 3):

From [cy.origin() and immediate redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74473421/cy-origin-and-immediate-redirect) try pushing the initial visit inside the `cy,origin()` something like this

```js
cy.origin('https://auth-service.ee', () => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('appUrl'));
  cy.get(locators.Button).click();
  cy.get('[data-tab="mobile-id"]').eq(1).click();
  cy.get("#mid-personal-code").clear().type("60001017771");
  cy.get("#mid-phone-number").clear().type("59700366{enter}");
})
```

I don't know why that works, but the example given is reproducible so maybe it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, tried that and received "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: The command was expected to run against origin https://auth-service.ee but the application is at origin https://application.ee.

Answer (score 0):

This is the weirdest outcome, but maybe it will help someone else too. After pausing the test, the login works (redirects to auth/mid/poll and then to organization main page). Also tried adding waits, but that doesn't work.
Now another issue is how to continue test after pausing, but that's another topic.
Thanks everyone!

[image]